# Show view controller in a subview

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, addsubview

Is it possible to show/add a view controller to a UIView? If yes could someone please help as I tried but am unable to figure it out. Down below is the current code that I'm using. Thanks in advance

```
if let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {

    //container view           
    let containerFrame  = CGRect(x: 0, y: keyWindow.frame.height, width: keyWindow.frame.width, height: 5)
    likesContainerView = UIView(frame: containerFrame)
    likesContainerView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    keyWindow.addSubview(likesContainerView!)

    //likes view controller
    let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "likesVC") as! likeViewController
    vc.view.frame = (likesContainerView?.frame)!
    self.addChildViewController(vc)
    likesContainerView?.addSubview(vc.view) //crashes here!!
    vc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)


    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        likesContainerView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:10, width: keyWindow.frame.width, height:500)

    }) { (_) in

    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, if you really are doing view controller containment and are going to animate `likesContainerView`, you really should do `didMove` from within the animation’s completion handler...

Answer (score 1):

When you do view controller containment (`addChild`, `addSubview`, `didMove`), the whole idea is to add it as a subview of a view within an existing view controller. The goal of these calls is to ensure that your view hierarchy stays in sync with your view controller hierarchy.

But you’re adding `vc.view` as a subview of `likesContainerView`, which you’ve added as subview of `keyWindow`. The whole idea is that a view controller’s view can have subview managed by another view controller.

Your `self` obviously references a view controller, so if you’re doing view controller containment, you should add `vc.view` as `subview` of the current `view`, not directly to `keyWindow`.

Comment: Ah ok thank you Rob for the explanation. So what your saying is that its not possible to add a view controller to a UIView within a keyWindow right?

Comment: I’m making a narrower assertion, namely that you shouldn’t do view containment calls (namely `addChild`, `didMove`) if you’re not doing view controller containment. If you do containment, add it as subview of view controller’s view. If you really must mess around with `keyWindow`, don’t use view controller containment.